# when i enter email/password in the login same is binded to the other form simultaneously.how can i avoid this and make it independent respectively?

Tags: angular, forms, frontend, angular-forms

```
I have a login page and it has two forms 1.signup 2.login form .both share same data model .
Signup and login functionalities works fine.but when i enter email/password the same is binded to the other form simultaneously.how can i avoid this and make it independent respectively ?
signup form


<form  #signupform="ngForm" class="needs-validation" (ngSubmit)="registeruser()" novalidate="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="reg-fn">User Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" required="" name="username"  #username="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.username" 
                [class.is-invalid]="username.invalid && username.touched">
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your user name!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
       
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="reg-email">E-mail Address</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="email" required="" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" name="emailidsu" #emailidsu="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.emailid"
                [class.is-invalid]="emailidsu.invalid && emailidsu.touched">
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter valid email address!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="reg-password">Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" required  name="passwordsu" #passwordsu="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.pwd" 
                [class.is-invalid]="passwordsu.invalid && passwordsu.touched">
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter password!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <div class="text-right">
        <button [disabled]="signupform.invalid" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have a login page and it has two forms 1.signup 2.login form .both share same data model .
Signup and login functionalities works fine.but when i enter email/password the same is binded to the other form simultaneously.how can i avoid this and make it independent respectively ?

login form

```
 <form  #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="loginuser()" class="needs-validation" novalidate="">
                        <small class="text-danger">{{msg}}</small>
                        <div class="input-group form-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-mail"><path d="M4 4h16c1.1 0 2 .9 2 2v12c0 1.1-.9 2-2 2H4c-1.1 0-2-.9-2-2V6c0-1.1.9-2 2-2z"></path><polyline points="22,6 12,13 2,6"></polyline></svg></span></div>
                            <input class="form-control" name="emailid"  type="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="user.emailid" required  #email="ngModel"
                            [class.is-invalid]="email.invalid && email.touched">
                           
                            <div class="invalid-feedback" >Please enter valid email address!</div>
                            
                        
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group form-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-lock"><rect x="3" y="11" width="18" height="11" rx="2" ry="2"></rect><path d="M7 11V7a5 5 0 0 1 10 0v4"></path></svg></span></div>
                            <input class="form-control" name="pwd" type="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="user.pwd"  required  #pwd="ngModel"
                            [class.is-invalid]="pwd.invalid && pwd.touched">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter valid password!</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" checked="" id="remember_me">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="remember_me">Remember me</label>
                            </div><a class="nav-link-inline font-size-sm" href="account-password-recovery.html">Forgot password?</a>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="mt-4">
                        <div class="text-right pt-4">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary"  [disabled]="loginForm.invalid"  type="submit">Sign In</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

screenshot

[image: login page]

Comment: Change one of these ```#loginForm="ngForm"``` to a different name

Comment: it already has different names. #signupform="ngForm"  and  #loginForm="ngForm".still I am not able to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

From a good design perspective, you should have two different data models for these two separate components. e.g one could be

```
type userSignUp = {
email: string
password: string
rememberMe: boolean
}
```

and other could be

```
type userCredential = {
 email: string;
password: string
}
```